# Android: MailCore library has text relocation error

Tags: android, text, android-emulator, mailcore2, relocation

The MailCore Library seems to be working fine on the android device but crashes while loading the MailCore lib on the emulator, with the following exception.

> AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                             Process: com.test.example, PID: 2492
>                                                                             java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed:
>   /data/app/com.test.example-1/lib/x86/libMailCore.so: has text
>   relocations
>                                                                                 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:977)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
>                                                                                 at com.libmailcore.MainThreadUtils.(MainThreadUtils.java:19)
>                                                                                 at com.libmailcore.MainThreadUtils.(MainThreadUtils.java:9)
>                                                                                 at com.libmailcore.MainThreadUtils.singleton(MainThreadUtils.java:14)
>                                                                                 at com.libmailcore.NativeObject.(NativeObject.java:42)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.test.example.Controllers.IMAP.IMAPSessionController.createNewSession(IMAPSessionController.java:17)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.test.example.Controllers.IMAP.IMAPSyncController.fetchFolderInfo(IMAPSyncController.kt:34)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.test.example.Services.FolderInfoService.onStartCommand(FolderInfoService.java:48)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3297)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
>                                                                                 at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                 at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
>                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)

Comment: Please also pass the context in your question what triggered the error.

Comment: @PrabodhM context given.